# How do I kill all of just one entity with /kill?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I like to play Minecraft and the bats are annoying and tried doing `/kill @e [type = bat]` then I pressed enter and all entities were killed. It ruined my world! How do I target the all of bats and ONLY the bats without killing anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spaces aren't allowed between selectors and their arguments. It'll be killing `@e` and ignoring everything after the space. Try:

```
/kill @e[type=bat]
```